# Fresh Install macos on T2-Mac with APFS

Tags: macos

I am doing a fresh install of macos Big Sur on a 16" MacBook Pro and I have managed to

- backup all files I need
- create a Big Sur install media
- boot from this USB drive (Disabling Secure Boot, enabling boot from external drive)

Now I am running Disk Utility and I am presented with the following state

1. **Internal** (this is my internal SSD drive)

   - Macintosh HD (this is an APFS volume)
   - Macintosh HD - Data  (this is an APFS volume)
2. **External** (this is the install media I created)

   - Install macOS Big Sur
3. **Disk Images** (Not sure what this is)

   - macOS Base System

In the past I just erased Macintosh HD (the only internal drive) and would install the OS on it. Everything from OS data and user data would be gone that way.
Now I want to achieve the same but Iam unsure if I should erase both or if maybe one contains OS stuff I should not erase. Is this structure/naming even required?

What should I do to have an absolute clean install OS, without bricking my machine?

Comment: I define the old as using the Disk Utility to erase the internal drive and then create a single Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume using a GUID Partition Map. If you did this, then you would be OK. The Big Sur installer would automatically convert to APFS.